# Apache Superset using different Date format while uploading CSV file

Tags: postgresql, visualization, apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset on a local machine. When I try to upload a CSV file into the database it is parsing Date in different format instead of what is provided in the CSV file.

For example:
My csv file has date in below format

```
01-08-2023            (i.e. 01 August 2023)
02-08-2023
21-08-2023
25-08-2023
```

and Superset in saving it as below.

```
08-01-2023
08-02-2023
21-08-2023
25-08-2023
```

How can I fix this issue?